# Paypal API to process payments to customers with paypal account balance zero?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-adaptive-payments, masspay

I'm trying to establish withdrawals facility to my customers using Paypal API. User can simply enter the email and place the request to which we transfer the amount from business account we use.

Here there is one issue, if my Paypal account balance is zero, we get a standard error message stating "Insufficient funds" where payment processing does not happen. But I want to process the payment here by using bank account associated to my paypal account immediately.

Is there any Paypal API that allows us to transfer funds directly from bank account if the paypal balance is zero or insufficient using bank account associated?

Please advise and put me in right direction.

Comment: Do you have a confirmed credit card added to the account?  If so, it should allow you to send funds using "instant transfer" when the PayPal funds don't cover it.  In that case it would send the money right away and submit the bank transfer to cover it, but if the bank transfer fails it would charge the credit card.

Comment: Thanks Andrew for immediate response. Yes I do have a business account to which a credit card is added. Do we have Instant Transfer API for Paypal, could you please guide me through right direction. My overall intention is users should be able to submit there paypal email and submit a form. Internally we make a api request to transfer amount to the users paypal account via any api method using email submitted. But this API should process the request without giving any insufficient funds error by transferring amount from credit card if paypal balance is zero.